# Counting how many times I used one equation until it reaches a specific result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math
#entrada

x=int(input("Put a number here:"))

#processo

num1=int(math.sqrt(x))
num2=round(num1,0)
num3=num2**2
remaining=x-num3

#saída

print("The remaining is:",remaining)
```

I made this code to get the remaining of a perfect square, for any "int" number, now I want to improve on this code so it keeps doing the equation using the last answer(stored in "remaining")is "0"(and stop calculating after that).

And then, after it finishes calculating, I want to count how many times I used the equation until it reaches "0"

I know this is hard to understand put ill try with one example:

For the number 87, the remaining will be 6 in this code because 87-(9²)=6, I want to use this result(6)and make the same equation and then the result will be (2) because 6-(2²)=2, then doing it again (1), then stop once it returns (0).

After that, I want to count how many times the equation was used to reach (0), in this example, it would be 4 (87 6)(6 2)(2 1)(1 0). And I want to print that counting...in this case(4)

I  know it is a lot to ask to help me in this(it's a big request), but I'm just staring programming now(10 days ago)and I couldn't find what I wanted anywhere else in the internet. Thanks for the help. Also, if there is any way to make mine original code better tell me please.

Comment: Instead of round you probably want to use np.floor to always round down. Put your code in a function and use that recursively.

Comment: Thanks @Joe yeah, you right I already changed it to math.floor(num1), thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
def count_squares(x):
    count = 0
    remaining = 1
    while remaining:
        min_square = (int(x**0.5) // 1) **2
        remaining = x - min_square
        count +=1
        print('X = {}, remaining = {}, count = {}'.format(x, remaining, count))
        x = remaining
    return count

print(count_squares(87))
```

Explaining:

- ** operator — for exponentiation.
- // operator  — for floor division. In this case it is similiar to "int" and "round" bound,  that you used for calculating num2, because "//1" will throw away all digits after dot. By the way int() function is not necessary in this case at all.
- we will exit from **while** loop as soon as remaining value will be equal to zero, because zero integer value  is interpreted as false.
- format is method of strings used to do formatting(surprisingly). All {} will be filled with arguments passed to the "format" method. There are other ways to do formatting in python( % operator, and formatted strings).

Output is:

```
X = 87, remaining = 6, Count = 1
X = 6, remaining = 2, Count = 2
X = 2, remaining = 1, Count = 3
X = 1, remaining = 0, Count = 4
4
```

Comment: yeah! that's it! All I did to add to that is putting x=int(input("type a number:")) before that, and changing the 87 number to x, it worked thank you a lot.